# Open windows explorer with specific path using system command

Tags: r, system

I found out that it is possible to open the windows explorer with a predefined path via the cmd.exe program using the following command:

```
explorer PATH
```

Back in R using the following command opens up the windows explorer:

```
system("explorer", intern=TRUE)
```

However, when I specify a path R returns the following warning message and does not open the explorer at the specified path:

```
> system("explorer C:\\Users\\xxx", intern=TRUE) 
character(0) 
attr(,"status") 
[1] 1 
Warning message: 
running command 'explorer C:\Users\xxx' had status 1
```

I quoted the \ otherwise R complained about not recognising \U from \Users.

However, when the command is executed as we would expect the double \ are replaced by only one .

When I copy paste the explorer C:\Users\xxx bit from the R warning message into the cmd.exe program the explorer is opened up at the specified path.

Does anybody have any idea why that fails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
shell("explorer C:\\Users\\xxx", intern=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hello! that worked. thanks a lot! I just updated my mac os R to 2.15.0 but it seems that there is no shell command for the Mac version...

Comment: Under MacOS you can use system("open /Applications/") etc

Answer (score 2):

I've created this simple function... I hope it'll be useful!

```
wopen <- function(x){
  y <- getwd()
  y <- gsub("/", "\\\\", y)
  shell(paste0("explorer ", y), intern = TRUE) 
}
```

Briefly: it takes the current directory, changes the slash direction and call to cmd.exe to open it. Regards.